# Movie I saw 30yrs ago where an abandoned facility contains cryogenic chambers containing humanoid aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m looking for a movie I had seen on VHS. All I remember was that there was a couple who snuck into an abandoned facility. Something happened while they were in a room with what I think were cryogenic chambers. What the chambers contained escaped and I think they were humanoid aliens but I don’t remember. Anyone have an idea what this was?

Comment: Did they trigger that escape?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you recall if the cryogenic chambers were positioned vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wonder if you're thinking of the 1983 film WAVELENGTH. [Here is the trailer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rziFM-MBek) In the film, two people sneak into a remote base where aliens are kept in cryo-ish tubes. They do get out of the tubes and are humanoid and bald and rather child-like. Here are images of the tubes where you can see the alien's heads, an alien, and the film's poster:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You guys are amazing. Thank you so much. Yes, it’s Wavelength. Wow. This has bothered me for years and I can now finally find it. Thank you. :D